# eclipse windowbuilder pro - incompatible java versions

Tags: java, windowbuilder, eclipse-indigo

Whenever I click on the design view I get this error message...

> Incompatible Java Versions
>
> Eclipse is running under 1.5, but this Java project has a 1.6 Java
>   compliance level, so WindowBuilder will not be able to load classes
>   from this project. Use a lower level of Java for the project, or run
>   Eclipse using a newer Java version.

I am running a fresh install of Indigo 3.7 Eclipse Classic with a few extra plugins, and installed WindowBuilder Pro from the 3.7 url.

I also have jre6 and jdk1.6.0_21 which I got in with javaEE and GlassFish also fresh installs.

What's happening here and can I fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Consider using **-vm** parameter to eclipse.ini.

```
-vm
/path/to/jdk/bin
```

And then cleaning your eclipse workspace ;)

Additional information about `-vm` option can be found [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM).

> Note the format of the -vm option - it is important to be exact:
>
> - The -vm option and its value (the path) must be on separate lines.
> - The value must be the full absolute or relative path to the Java executable, not just to the Java home directory.
> - The -vm option must occur before the -vmargs option, since everything after -vmargs is passed directly to the JVM.

Comment: just tried it... added this to the eclipse.ini
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin
and started eclipse with the -clean argument... but no dice.  Does it matter where I put the -vm parameter in the ini file?

Comment: No, order doesn't matter. But param-name & param-value is needed to be put in diff line, as the given snippet. Then you can try creating a new workspace and open project from there.

Comment: I believe that order *does* matter in eclipse.ini. In particular, -vm needs to precede -vmargs.

Comment: I will verify again, and let you guys know